# Passing props state props using context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I want to pass my state value name to another component Context3.js without using props. I have use context api for creating context and through provider I have passed the value.
Now at Context3.js I am trying to consume it but at output screen I am unbale to see my output.

```js
import './App.css';
import Context3 from './Components/Context3';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Context3/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The main component is App.js.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

class Context1 extends Component{
       state={
            name: 'mohammed'
       }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.name}>
            </MyContext.Provider>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Context1;
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './Context1';

class Context3 extends Component{
    render(){  
        return(
            <div>
                <MyContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        value => <h1> {value} </h1> 
                    }
                </MyContext.Consumer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Context3;
```

strong text

Comment: Where do you render Context1 (the context provider)?

Comment: in App.js I am rendering

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your children with the ContextProvider (Context1)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export const MyContext = React.createContext();

class Context1 extends Component{
       state={
            name: 'mohammed'
       }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <MyContext.Provider value={this.state.name}>
              {this.props.children}
            </MyContext.Provider>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Context1;
```

```js
import './App.css';
import Context1 from './Components/Context1';
import Context3 from './Components/Context3';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Context1>
        <Context3/>
      </Context1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```